# how to check if RestKit is currently running

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-data, restkit-0.20

How can i check that`RestKit 0.2x` is currently running or not, i.e. doing mappings and saving to the persistent store ? because I want to do some operations on the persistent store and `RestKit` must not be running at that moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two main operation queues that matter for this purpose:

1. The `operationQueue` of your `RKObjectManager`
2. The `[RKObjectRequestOperation responseMappingQueue]` (see [API Docs](http://restkit.org/api/latest/Classes/RKObjectRequestOperation.html#//api/name/responseMappingQueue))

If the count on these queues is zero then nothing is happening (assuming you have not started any operations manually). You can suspend these queues.

Comment: how can I stop these queues during its run ? I've tried sending the message cancelAllOperations to both queues but to no avail ..

Answer (score 1):

You're triggering each operation that RestKit performs, and deciding (by how you trigger it) which queue(s) the various operations are running on. You can either maintain a counter yourself (increment before each request and decrement in the completion/failure callbacks) or get the queue and check how many operations are on it.